# Android端末からWebAPI実行で「connection-refused」となる

Tags: python, google-app-engine

GAE/PY (standard environment) で、とあるWebAPIを実装しました。

このWebAPIをAndroid端末から実行したのですが、
「connection-refused」となりました。

下記は確認したのですが、どのようなことが考えられますでしょうか？
また、GCP公式ドキュメント上に「connection-refused」となる条件が記載ありますでしょうか。

■確認したこと
 1. 再現性は無し
　１時間程度で解消しました。それ以降は発生しませんでした。
 2. GCP側にトラブルはなかった
　事象発生の時間帯にGCPトラブルはありませんでした。
　https://status.cloud.google.com/
 3. クライアントの制限はしていない
　ファイアーウォールにてIP制限はしていません
　IAPによる制限はしていません
 4. Stackdriver logging にリクエストログなし
　事象発生時にrequest_log はありませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

teratailで質問された [Connection refused エラーの検証と原因の特定方法](https://teratail.com/questions/62189) への回答が参考になるのではないかと思いますので、一読されることをお勧めします。